# Hibernate deepValidate:false exception in grails

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

I have a wierd problem which is occurring only on the reference server and the same code at my local environment works as expected. I am trying to do a batch update after reading some records.

The JAVA Code I have written is

```
public OrderDTO findRecurringOrder(Integer userId, Integer itemId) {
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(OrderDTO.class)
                .createAlias("orderStatus", "s")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("s.id", Constants.ORDER_STATUS_ACTIVE))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("deleted", 0))
                .createAlias("baseUserByUserId", "u")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("u.id", userId))
                .createAlias("orderPeriod", "p")
                .add(Restrictions.ne("p.id", Constants.ORDER_PERIOD_ONCE))
                .createAlias("lines", "l")
                .createAlias("l.item", "i")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("i.id", itemId))
                .addOrder(Order.desc("id"))
                .setMaxResults(1);

        return findFirst(criteria);
    }

public T findFirst(Criteria criteria) {
        criteria.setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(1);
        return (T) criteria.uniqueResult();

    }
```

The error stacktrace I am getting is:

`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.sapienter.jbilling.server.order.db.OrderLineDTO.validate() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[deepValidate:false]]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onPreUpdate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.groovy:168)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:996)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1589)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:328)
    at com.sapienter.jbilling.server.util.db.AbstractDAS.findFirst(AbstractDAS.java:212)
    at com.sapienter.jbilling.server.order.db.OrderDAS.findRecurringOrder(OrderDAS.java:88)
    at com.sapienter.jbilling.server.mediation.task.SubscriptionEventProcessor.doEventAction(SubscriptionEventProcessor.java:134)
    at com.sapienter.jbilling.server.mediation.task.AbstractResolverMediationTask.resolve(AbstractResolverMediationTask.java:126)
    at com.sapienter.jbilling.server.mediation.task.AbstractResolverMediationTask.process(AbstractResolverMediationTask.java:93)
    at com.sapienter.jbilling.server.mediation.MediationSessionBean.normalizeRecordGroup(MediationSessionBean.java:476)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy75.normalizeRecordGroup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sapienter.jbilling.server.mediation.MediationSessionBean.performMediation(MediationSessionBean.java:232)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy75.performMediation(Unknown Source)
    at com.sapienter.jbilling.server.mediation.MediationSessionBean$1.run(MediationSessionBean.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)`

Any suggestions, I really have very little idea about this Hibernate exception ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like a Hibernate error. Take a look at the first line:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.sapienter.jbilling.server.order.db.OrderLineDTO.validate() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[deepValidate:false]]
```

Apparently somewhere else you're calling **validate()** in an object of type **OrderLineDTO** and passing a Map ([deepValidate:false]) when you only need to pass (deepValidate:false). There are other uses of validate you can check [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html).